Athena Cache Is there way to clear it all down
In Athena we can use the reuse query results config in Java to reuse results. (Reusing query results - Amazon Athena)
Is there a way to clear down the cache from within java - api call, so that I can say from this point start caching again?
I understand I can do per query but I want to do it at a more broader level. Rather having to do it for each query.

Query result reuse isn't really a cache, it's an instruction to reuse the result of a previously run (identical) query.
If you don't want to reuse a previous result, i.e. run the query and not get a potentially outdated result, you just don't request results to be reused. This is the default state. Results are only reused when the query includes configuration that explicitly requests results to be reused.
In the console, there is a toggle in the lower right corner that enables or disables query result reuse. If it's off results are not reused. In the API (SDK, CLI) you just don't set the result reuse properties, or explicitly disable them.
Query result reuse will reuse the most recent results that are found for a previously run (identical) query. I think that thinking about query result reuse as a cache doesn't help, but if this is your mental model, you can think of running a query with query result reuse disabled (with the toggle in the console, or by not requesting it through the API) will seed the cache with a new value. Any subsequent (identical) query with query result reuse enabled will reuse the result from that query, as long as it's not too old.
In other words, if you are using the Java SDK to run Athena queries, either set the Enabled property of ResultReuseByAgeConfiguration to false for one query, and any subsequent query with Enabled set to true will pick up the results from the run where Enabled was false, until MaxAgeInMinutes has passed.

you are correct thinking of it like a cache was incorrect. I understand the reuse configuration. What i wanted was the ablity to of something similar to evict.. and then start reusing queries again.
I know that can be done by settting false and then true for reuse.. i was looking for a one api call that would just say dont use any previous queries but store the ones that come after this point. Rather than setting the flag and unsetting it from false to true.
